# How to style a table with only partly border spacing?

Tags: html, css, html-table, border-spacing

I want to create a table with only partly separated borders. The borders above and below the `thead` should be without spaces in between. But others in it should be separated by a small space.

Unfortunately, the `border-spacing` style only applies to the whole table: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing

For example, in the following I want to have space only between the `border-top` of `h2.1` and `h2.2`. Is that possible?

HTML:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">h1</th>
      <th colspan="2">h2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>h2.1</th>
      <th>h2.2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>b1</td>
      <td>b2.1</td>
      <td>b2.2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>b1</td>
      <td>b2.1</td>
      <td>b2.2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
}

th,
td {
  vertical-align: top;
}

thead tr:first-child th {
  border-top: 2px solid;
}

thead tr:not(:first-child) th {
  border-top: 1px solid;
}

tbody tr:first-child td {
  border-top: 1px solid;
}

tbody tr {
  border-top: 1px solid;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6ov4hadd/

**Edit**

Here is a more sensible example.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lnk929q4/

I want to look it like a "book table":

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try using two different tables for head part and body part. Something like this

https://jsfiddle.net/6ov4hadd/1/

```
        <table id = "table1">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th rowspan="2">h1</th>
              <th colspan="2">h2</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>h2.1</th>
              <th>h2.2</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          </table>
          <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>b1</td>
              <td>b2.1</td>
              <td>b2.2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>b1</td>
              <td>b2.1</td>
              <td>b2.2</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: Thanks. But I need the inner borders of the thead with spacing and the outer borders without. Your solution has the border below the head with spacing but the inner ones without.

Comment: Sorry @Daniel im not able to get your expect output. Can you give a rough picture. It will be helpfull.

Comment: I have added a more sensible example with a picture.